# Sorting NSFetchedResultsController alphabetically and in sections

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController to manage my tableView, I am trying to sort the entity into sections alphabetically, similar to how your contacts app would look. I am getting this error when trying to run my code: `the entity Exercise is not key value coding-compliant for the key "nameFirstChar".'`

`nameFirstChar` is a computed property in the `Exercise` subclass as seen here:

```
var nameFirstChar: String {
        get {
            if let char = self.name?.first {
                return String(char)
            }
            return "#"
        }
    }
```

this is how I set up my NSFetchedResultsController:

```
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Exercise> = Exercise.fetchRequest()
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: DataController.shared.context, sectionNameKeyPath: "nameFirstChar", cacheName: nil)
```

Not sure what is causing this problem, anyone have any insight?

Comment: That seems extremely clunky, is there not a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think that is true, for a different NSFetchedResultsController I am using a computed String for the section key path

Comment: You're right.  I created a test app and your problem is a lack of `@objc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you mark your computed property as `@objc`, otherwise it is not visible to the Core Data framework (which is written in Objective C).

```
@objc var nameFirstChar: String {
    return String(self.lastName?.first ?? "#").uppercased()
}
```

Comment: not sure if it's needed but I am also using ```@objc dynamic var```